# Unpickling a function into a different context in Python

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have written a Python interface to a process-centric job distribution system we're developing/using internally at my workplace. While reasonably skilled programmers, the primary people using this interface are research scientists, not software developers, so ease-of-use and keeping the interface out of the way to the greatest degree possible is paramount.

My library unrolls a sequence of inputs into a sequence of pickle files on a shared file server, then spawns jobs that load those inputs, perform the computation, pickle the results, and exit; the client script then picks back up and produces a generator that loads and yields the results (or rethrows any exception the calculation function did.)

This is only useful since the calculation function itself is one of the serialized inputs. cPickle is quite content to pickle function references, but requires the pickled function to be reimportable in the same context. This is problematic. I've already solved the problem of finding the module to reimport it, but the vast majority of the time, it is a top-level function that is pickled and, thus, does not have a module path. The only strategy I've found to be able to unpickle such a function on the computation nodes is this nauseating little approach towards simulating the original environment in which the function was pickled before unpickling it:

```
...
# At this point, we've identified the source of the target function.
# A string by its name lives in "modname".
# In the real code, there is significant try/except work here.

targetModule = __import__(modname)
globalRef = globals()
for thingie in dir(targetModule):
    if thingie not in globalRef:
        globalRef[thingie] = targetModule.__dict__[thingie]

# sys.argv[2]: the path to the pickle file common to all jobs, which contains
# any data in common to all invocations of the target function, then the
# target function itself
commonFile = open(sys.argv[2], "rb")
commonUnpickle = cPickle.Unpickler(commonFile)
commonData = commonUnpickle.load()
# the actual function unpack I'm having trouble with:
doIt = commonUnpickle.load()
```

The final line is the most important one here- it's where my module is picking up the function it should actually be running. This code, as written, works as desired, but directly manipulating the symbol tables like this is unsettling.

How can I do this, or something very much like this that does not force the research scientists to separate their calculation scripts into a proper class structure (they use Python like the most excellent graphing calculator ever and I would like to continue to let them do so) the way Pickle desperately wants, without the unpleasant, unsafe, and just plain scary `__dict__`-and-`globals()` manipulation I'm using above? I fervently believe there has to be a better way, but `exec "from {0} import *".format("modname")` didn't do it, several attempts to inject the pickle load into the `targetModule` reference didn't do it, and `eval("commonUnpickle.load()", targetModule.__dict__, locals())` didn't do it. All of these fail with Unpickle's `AttributeError` over being unable to find the function in `<module>`.

What is a better way?

Comment: Have you considered [`marshal`](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) instead? It's the usual way to persist "code objects" (though for all I know you might have all the same problems as you have with `cPickle`).

Comment: `marshal` can't pack user-defined data types, such as the object around the function if my target function is actually an instance function- a scenario that works correctly here. The suggestions on packing up the `__code__` are helpful (and help me solve a different problem I have somewhere else), but don't solve the "and your little context, too! _evil cackle_' problem space I'm aiming at.

Answer (score 2):

Pickling functions can be rather annoying if trying to move them into a different context. If the function does not reference anything from the module that it is in and references (if anything) modules that are guaranteed to be imported, you might check some code from a [Rudimentary Database Engine](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577825/) found on the Python Cookbook.

In order to support views, the academic module grabs the code from the callable when pickling the query. When it comes time to unpickle the view, a LambdaType instance is created with the code object and a reference to a namespace containing all imported modules. The solution has limitations but worked well enough for the exercise.

---

**Example for Views**

```
class _View:

    def __init__(self, database, query, *name_changes):
        "Initializes _View instance with details of saved query."
        self.__database = database
        self.__query = query
        self.__name_changes = name_changes

    def __getstate__(self):
        "Returns everything needed to pickle _View instance."
        return self.__database, self.__query.__code__, self.__name_changes

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        "Sets the state of the _View instance when unpickled."
        database, query, name_changes = state
        self.__database = database
        self.__query = types.LambdaType(query, sys.modules)
        self.__name_changes = name_changes
```

---

Sometimes is appears necessary to make modifications to the registered modules available in the system. If for example you need to make reference to the first module (`__main__`), you may need to create a new module with your available namespace loaded into a new module object. The [same recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577825/) used the following technique.

---

**Example for Modules**

```
def test_northwind():
    "Loads and runs some test on the sample Northwind database."
    import os, imp
    # Patch the module namespace to recognize this file.
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
    module = imp.new_module(name)
    vars(module).update(globals())
    sys.modules[name] = module
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on packing the `__code__` and working with that- I wasn't aware of it at all. Unfortunately, I'd like to be able to handle a function that's actually part of a class instance (if, say, it's a function of the primary data storage type), which Pickle transparently does, but this would fail at. It's useful, though, and I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was long, and I was too caffeinated to make it through your very long question… However, I think you are looking to do something that there's a pretty good existing solution for already.  There's a fork of the `parallel python` (i.e. `pp`) library that takes functions and objects and serializes them, sends them to different servers, and then unpikles and executes them.  The fork lives inside the `pathos` package, but you can download it independently here:

http://danse.cacr.caltech.edu/packages/dev_danse_us

The "other context" in that case is another server… and the objects are transported by converting the objects to source code and then back to objects.

If you are looking to use pickling, much in the way you are doing already, there's an extension to `mpi4py` that serializes arguments and functions, and returns pickled return values…  The package is called `pyina`, and is commonly used to ship code and objects to cluster nodes in coordination with a cluster scheduler.

Both `pathos` and `pyina` provide `map` abstractions (and `pipe`), and try to hide all of the details of parallel computing behind the abstractions, so scientists don't need to learn anything except how to program normal serial python.  They just use one of the `map` or `pipe` functions, and get parallel or distributed computing.

Oh, I almost forgot.  The `dill` serializer includes `dump_session` and `load_session` functions that allow the user to easily serialize their entire interpreter session and send it to another computer (or just save it for later use).  That's pretty handy for changing contexts, in a different sense.

Get `dill`, `pathos`, and `pyina` here:  https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 1):

For a module to be recognized as loaded I think it must by in sys.modules, not just its *content* imported into your global/local namespace. Try to exec everything, then get the result out of an artificial environment.

```
env = {"fn": sys.argv[2]}
code = """\
import %s  # maybe more
import cPickle
commonFile = open(fn, "rb")
commonUnpickle = cPickle.Unpickler(commonFile)
commonData = commonUnpickle.load()
doIt = commonUnpickle.load()
"""
exec code in env
return env["doIt"]
```

Comment: That's not an expression, it's two statements- eval only works on single expressions. I tried equivalent code using `exec` and, unfortunately, got nowhere.

Comment: Right, eval won't work. However I have done something similiar once in a complicated test setup routine. Updating example.

Answer (score 0):

While functions are advertised as first-class objects in Python, this is one case where it can be seen that they are really second-class objects.  It is the reference to the callable, not the object itself, that is pickled.  (You cannot directly pickle a `lambda` expression.)

There is an alternate usage of `__import__` that you might prefer:

```
def importer(modulename, symbols=None):
  u"importer('foo') returns module foo; importer('foo', ['bar']) returns {'bar': object}"
  if modulename in sys.modules: module = sys.modules[modulename]
  else: module = __import__(modulename, fromlist=['*'])
  if symbols == None: return module
  else: return dict(zip(symbols, map(partial(getattr, module), symbols)))
```

So these would all be basically equivalent:

```
from mymodule.mysubmodule import myfunction
myfunction = importer('mymodule.mysubmodule').myfunction
globals()['myfunction'] = importer('mymodule.mysubmodule', ['myfunction'])['myfunction']
```